# using adapter with proxy to use 3rd party libraries

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to use some excel manipulation 3rd party library. This library is using some interfaces to work with workbooks and worksheets. so I tried to use adapter pattern in order to decouple from the 3rd party library. I have used adapter for workbooks and worksheets. 
As you know there are many worksheets in a workbook. storing worksheet adapters in the workbook adapter is a solution but it seems a little hard to manage and synchronize the worksheets in my code and the library. So it seems using some proxy for list of the worksheets is the answer. but also it seems like using a hammer to kill the fly. so the problem is what is the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I cannot get any kind of further details, but your approach seems to be a sensible solution. However, a desing pattern is not an answer to a concrete problem, but a general strategy to deal with it. Then the more you can do is to argue why the design matches correctly what you are trying to solve:

- Since the Facade pattern is more appropiate to simplify an interface for a subsystem, the structural pattern which fits better in this scenario and is commonly used is the Adapter.
- Like in the classic example of the `ProxyImage` and the `RealImage`, using a proxy for the worksheets avoids loading them when it is not necessary. Besides, if you combine it with the adapter, you get the same advantages as in the previous case.

[image]

Finally, I don't think your solution is overly complicated and in the long term worth it: It is a reasonable effort to reduce coupling with a 3rd party library, but without adding too much complexity.